# Can't run vb.net application as administrator across network

Tags: vb.net

I have created a small application that auto elevates as administrator using the command:

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false"
```

This works fine if I run the application locally on the computer.  However, if the computer tries to run my execuatable across the netork, it simply crashes on startup with a message "Do you want to send more information about the problem?" error.  If I right click and run as administrator, my application will work and will prompt for admin credentials.

The folder I am running my application from (across the network) has full read/write permissions for 'everyone'.

My question is: Is there something I've missed?  Why can I run my application locally and not get prompted but across the network crashes or requires admin?

Can anyone help explain what might be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**
I have checked my event viewer log and it shows the following:

Application: AutoUpdater.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Stack:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener..ctor(System.Net.IPAddress, Int32)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel.SetupChannel()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpServerChannel..ctor(System.Collections.IDictionary, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IServerChannelSinkProvider, System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IAuthorizeRemotingConnection)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.RegisterChannel(ChannelType, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[])
   at AutoUpdater.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])

I don't understand why it is making reference to System.Net.Sockets??  But that is what seems to be crashing my app.

Comment: I'm not shure about your question. Are you trying to execute an application from a LAN folder? or what?
This generally won't work if your program is not all in a single file.

Comment: Can you try to copy/paste the inner exception (if it is available?) Sockets are used to make connections to certain programs (ftp, file sharing, databases, etc.), so if you application is trying to connect to certain services, then that may be the issue. Try posting some code of what it is doing so we can see what the issue may be.

Comment: Have you granted trust to your application on the machines that are running it?  See @SpectralGhost answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the other computers attempting to run your application have the correct .Net framework versions installed. If users are able to open the executable, there *shouldn't* be any other issues with permission.

If you have verified the framework versions, see if there is anything in the error report that might point to a reason for the crash. A lot of times there may be something in there that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Have updated my post with the error found in the event viewer.

Answer (score 0):

.NET applications don't like to run from the intranet by default.

Try this:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration
2. Click Configure Code Access Security Policy link
3. Click Adjust Zone Security
4. Set the My Computer and Local Intranet to Full Trust

If this works, then it is a local security issue. If you need it scripted out, you can use the caspol exe that is in the framework. Sample

```
C:
cd %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1. -URL Z:\folder\EXEName.exe FullTrust -n FriendlyNameOfEXE
```